# What is the time format of Windows Event Log?

Tags: c#, event-log

Which format does this stirng `2010-06-19T06:28:01.077148400Z` belong to?

It represents 6/19/2010 11:58:01 AM.

I tried parsing the string to DateTime.Parse() and the DateTime object represents the above time. Now I want to convert that DateTime object to the format once again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your user information, it looks like you're in an Indian time zone - the [New Delhi](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=176) zone is 5 hours and thirty minutes ahead of [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The "Z" at the end of the date/time string indicates UTC, which makes sense: 6:28 UTC is 11:58 in your time zone.

You can take a local `DateTime` and convert it to UTC using `ToUniversalTime` - but if you want to get the current time, you can just use `DateTime.UtcNow` to start with.

Once you've got a `DateTime` in UTC, this format string would format it in the same way:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff00K
```

This is very similar to the round-trip format, just with the extra two zeroes at the end. Those are hard-coded to 0 as `DateTime` doesn't have precision beyond a tenth of a microsecond, whereas your sample string has it down to a nanosecond.

For example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
string s = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff00K",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

creates something like this:

```
2010-06-19T13:57:15.885578200Z
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out from the answer XIII gave me. But you deserve the credit for giving a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Universaltime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(VS.71).aspx) to me.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: What happened with the editing? I don't see a change and why was it needed?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the representation of a DateTime using the [Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip):

```
var s = "2010-06-19T06:28:01.077148400Z";

var dt = DateTime.Parse(s, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("o"));  //  prints "2010-06-19T06:28:01.0771484Z"
```

Comment: Did you look at the printed result? "2010-06-19T06:28:01.0771484Z" - note the missing two final 0s.

Comment: Skeet! You win! But only this time! \*shakes fist\*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UTC formatted in [round-trip format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip).

Comment: Not quite: it's got 9 decimal places on the seconds, not 7.